# Binary print not working in C

Tags: c, while-loop, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to print binary using bit mask of 32 bit in c but the binary representation is not getting printed in the if statement.

```
unsigned int bit_mask = 2147483648;
int decimal = 2;
printf("\nBinary representation of 2: \n");
while(bit_mask > 0){
    if((decimal & bit_mask) == 0)
        printf("0");
    else
        printf("1");
    bit_mask = bit_mask >> 1;
}

decimal = 255;
printf("\n\nBinary representation of 255: \n");
while(bit_mask > 0){
    if((decimal & bit_mask) == 0)
        printf("0");
    else
        printf("1");
    bit_mask = bit_mask >> 1;
}

decimal = 32;
printf("\n\nBinary representation of 32: \n");
while(bit_mask > 0){
    if((decimal & bit_mask) == 0)
        printf("0");
    else
        printf("1");
    bit_mask = bit_mask >> 1;
}

decimal = -1;
printf("\n\nBinary representation of -1: \n");
while(bit_mask > 0){
    if((decimal & bit_mask) == 0)
        printf("0");
    else
        printf("1");
    bit_mask = bit_mask >> 1;
}

decimal = -255;
printf("\n\nBinary representation of -255: \n");
while(bit_mask > 0){
    if((decimal & bit_mask) == 0)
        printf("0");
    else
        printf("1");
    bit_mask = bit_mask >> 1;
}

int random_number =  (rand() % INT_MAX) + (rand() % INT_MIN);
printf("\n\nBinary representation of %d: \n", random_number);
while(bit_mask > 0){
    if((random_number & bit_mask) == 0)
        printf("0");
    else
        printf("1");
    bit_mask = bit_mask >> 1;
}
```

PS: the program is now only working for `2` but still not printing the other values (255, 32, -1, -255)

Comment: Have you tried printing `bit_mask` before the loop?  It's either zero or very negative (like -2147483648), isn't it?  The trouble is the value you're trying to store in `bit_mask` is bigger than `INT_MAX`, so you get unexpected behaviour.  Maybe you should use an `unsigned int`, which probably has other advantages (like shift zeros instead of ones into the most significant bit).

Comment: `int bit_mask = 2147483648;` --> `unsigned bit_mask = 2147483648;`, `2 & bit_mask` --> `1 & bit_mask`, `bit_mask >> 1;` --> `bit_mask >>= 1;` Also, the result is reversed.

Comment: @Uriel: no digits; the loop condition is false so nothing is printed by the loop.  Just the heading line.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: are you sure about the 'reversed' part?  The `2` is the value being printed (it should be a variable, of course).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the reply but after using unsigned int the loop goes infinite and keeps printing zeros infinitely

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It means that it is displayed from the lower bit.

Comment: @Ruby: Well, that's because there are also the other problems that BLUEPIXY diagnosed.  You're not altering the mask, so it keeps on going, and going, and going.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: On the first iteration, the mask has the most significant bit set; this is checked with the value, and 0 is printed.  If the shift was stored, the next iteration would check the next most significant bit, etc.  Isn't that printing the bits in the normal (non-reversed) sequence?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There is no value(variable, already pointed :-) in the supplied code to perform operation with the **mask**. So the values themselves used as masks are displayed in reverse order. I do not think we need to discuss this with you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  It is another if `2` itself wants to display as binary. I was misunderstood about it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It's misleading at a glance, but the 2 in the `if` statement is the value being displayed in base 2, and `bit_mask` really is a bit mask (it's `0x80000000` in hex, and should be declared `unsigned`).

Comment: @Ruby You need to reset `bit_mask`. Or replace the processing with a function.

Comment: As rather commonly seen in these questions, this is not decimal to binary conversion at all. It is binary to binary-coded ASCII. If it was decimal conversion it would be full of divisions and modulos by 10.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks it worked. Also for negative numbers do I need to take 1s complement using ~?

Comment: It is not necessary. For example, like `(unsigned)decimal`.

Comment: reduce code like [this](https://ideone.com/GJIBzK)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for the code but that is way too high level for me

Comment: With the updated code, then (a) you need to use a function to encapsulate the logic, and (b) you need to set `mask` back to `0x80000000` (or `2147483648`) before you start processing each number.  Note that the reset would happen automatically if you used a function and set `mask` on entry to that function.

Answer (score 1):

If the fixups suggested by BLUEPIXY and myself are made, the code will produce the answer with the bits in the correct sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned value = 2; value < 1024; value = value * 3 + 1)
    {
        unsigned bit_mask = 0x80000000;  // 2147483648

        printf("Binary representation of %3u: ", value);
        while (bit_mask > 0)
        {
            if ((value & bit_mask) == 0)
                printf("0");
            else
                printf("1");
            bit_mask >>= 1;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Binary representation of   2: 00000000000000000000000000000010
Binary representation of   7: 00000000000000000000000000000111
Binary representation of  22: 00000000000000000000000000010110
Binary representation of  67: 00000000000000000000000001000011
Binary representation of 202: 00000000000000000000000011001010
Binary representation of 607: 00000000000000000000001001011111
```

The output is not reversed, despite what [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) says in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780484/binary-print-not-working-in-c/46780635#comment80507091_46780484).

---

The body of the loop could be converted into a function such as `void print_binary(unsigned value)` with minimal effort, and that would then be called from a loop.  The edited question with more or less the same loop written out six(!) times is a travesty — do not write code like that.  When you copy'n'paste code like that, there is a function waiting to be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_binary(unsigned value)
{
    unsigned bit_mask = 0x80000000;  // 2147483648

    while (bit_mask > 0)
    {
        if ((value & bit_mask) == 0)
            printf("0");
        else
            printf("1");
        bit_mask >>= 1;
    }
}
```

This function can be used to print the binary representation of an `unsigned int` without adding any decoration.  It can be used reasonably generally.  In this specific context, you might write a wrapper function
to handle the other formatting:

```
void fmt_binary(int value)
{
    printf("Binary representation of %3d: ", value);
    print_binary((unsigned)value);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The cast is not necessary as long as you have a prototype for `print_binary()` in scope.  From C99 onwards, you must have a function declaration present, but that doesn't have to be a prototype.  However, compiling without prototypes present is silly.  And you should find the options that ensure your compiler complains if you try to skimp.  For GCC, you might use:

```
gcc -std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes …
```

You might or might not add `-Wold-style-declaration` or `-Wold-style-definition` depending on the code base you're dealing with and the version of GCC you're using (and on how careless you are in writing code).  There are other options you'd consider, like `-Wshadow`, but if your code compiles cleanly with what's shown, it is unlikely to run into many problems that aren't logic problems.

With `fmt_binary()` defined, you can write `main()`:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// … declarations or definitions of fmt_binary and print_binary

int main(void)
{
    for (int value = 2; value < 1024; value = value * 3 + 1)
        fmt_binary(value);
    fmt_binary(2);
    fmt_binary(255);
    fmt_binary(32);
    fmt_binary(-1);
    fmt_binary(-255);
    srand(time(0));     // Better than no call to srand()
    int random_number =  (rand() % INT_MAX) + (rand() % INT_MIN);
    fmt_binary(random_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output might be:

```
Binary representation of   2: 00000000000000000000000000000010
Binary representation of   7: 00000000000000000000000000000111
Binary representation of  22: 00000000000000000000000000010110
Binary representation of  67: 00000000000000000000000001000011
Binary representation of 202: 00000000000000000000000011001010
Binary representation of 607: 00000000000000000000001001011111
Binary representation of   2: 00000000000000000000000000000010
Binary representation of 255: 00000000000000000000000011111111
Binary representation of  32: 00000000000000000000000000100000
Binary representation of  -1: 11111111111111111111111111111111
Binary representation of -255: 11111111111111111111111100000001
Binary representation of -1758826555: 10010111001010100110111111000101
```

Comment: Better, but any programmer of mine who wrote `bit_mask = 2147483648` instead of `bit_mask = 0x80000000` would still be slapped.