# Decimal to binary converter not working correctly

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I have written a decimal to binary converter and am having some trouble with it.
It works fine for all decimal numbers < 16, but for any numbers that require a binary length larger than 4 it seems to go haywire and I'm not sure why.

When running the code, no matter the input, the length of the string *binary* is always 3, despite me declaring the char array *binary* to be of size *count*, which is correctly displaying the length of the binary number needed to represent the decimal number

I must be overlooking something really basic, but for the life of me I can't see what it is.
Any help would be appreciated

**edit**

I presume it must be something to do with declaring the size of the char array with the use of a variable, should I instead be using malloc/calloc?

> char binary[count];
>
> int length = strlen(binary);
>
> printf("Length of string is %d \n", length);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int input;
    int decimal;
    int count;

    printf("Please enter a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    decimal = input;
    count = floor(log(decimal)/ log(2)) +1;

    printf("Length of binary needed %d \n", count);
    char binary[count];
    int length = strlen(binary);
    printf("Length of string is %d \n", length);
    for(count; count >= 0; count--)
    {
        if(pow(2, count) <= decimal)
        {
            decimal -= pow(2, count);
            binary[length - count] = '1';
        }
        else
            binary[length - count] = '0';

    }
    printf("%d is represented by %s in binary \n", input, binary);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t be using the functions from `<math.h>`.

Comment: care to explain why?

Comment: You have not allowed space to store a null byte at the end of the string, not have you ensured that the string is null terminated, and you didn’t use a variant of `printf()` format that would prevent this being a problem.  I’m not sure it’s the cause of your trouble, but it isn’t good.

Comment: You shouldn’t be using the functions from `<math.h>` because they’re heavy duty and slow. Also, they’re liable to inaccuracies; they provide an approximation to some answers.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I'm fairly new to the way C handles things like this. I presume I'd have to declare my string to be of size count + 1 then just append a '/0' character at the last position?

Comment: fair enough, although what alternatives do I have when it comes to using logs and powers, apart from writing my own functions? Im sure, despite how slow and innacurate the standard math.h functions are, if i were to write the functions they'd be significantly worse, I can assure you that

Comment: Ensuring null termination — yes, you'd add another 1 to the length and set the last byte to `'\0'` (backslash, not slash) after the loop.  There are many ways to format the string without using `pow()` — or `log()` or `floor()`.  One effective way is to allocate enough space for the maximum requirement (`sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1`, where `CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>` but is normally 8), and then assign a null byte at the end and assign to positions from the end, stopping when the value reaches 0.  You pick off the last bit with `value & 1`; you use `value /= 2;` or `value >>= 1;`.

Comment: Note that your algorithm blows up on negative integers — the logarithm of a negative number is a complex number, so all hell breaks loose.  With the bit shifting, you have to be careful to avoid negative numbers too; you use unsigned arithmetic.  There are many other questions asking about conversion to binary string format.  I answered [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780484/binary-print-not-working-in-c/46780635#46780635) last week.

Comment: There are other questions about converting to binary string representation, but they're not easy to find, let alone to find good ones.  Converting from a binary string notation (sequence of `'0'` and `'1'` characters) is easy: [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) and family accept a base of 2 and do the job admirably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char binary[count];
int length = strlen(binary);
```

`binary` here has been allocated but not initialised to anything. It could contain anything - so what do you expect the length to be?

Comment: Just changed it to int length = count; and it seems to have solved it. I figured the strlen function would return the size of the array, considering I allocated it but havent intialised it, I figured it might just contain NULL values, but that strlen would still work. Apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: No, it counts the number of characters up to the first `NULL`. So it depends on what's in there, which is usually random junk.

Comment: Ah, I see, knew I was being dumb.
Thanks for your help!